# texlive.asc BAD gpg signature since 2 days

Tags: texlive, ctan, texlive-2021

I'm building a docker latex container, and since 2 days, I cannot build anymore.

As it appears, the verification of the files `install-tl-unx.tar.gz.sha512.asc` (taken from [this mirror here](https://mirror.koddos.net/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet/)) fails with the key `texlive.asc` (found here : https://tug.org/texlive/files/).

1. `install-tl-unx.tar.gz.*` have been (re)generated on **2021-07-26 01:55**
2. `texlive.asc`  dates from **2020-04-06 04:44**.

Moreover, in the [TUG repo](https://tug.org/texlive/files/), the files `texlive.asc` and `texlive2020.asc` are the same. **I suspect that the new texlive.asc for texlive 2021 hasn't been put in the repo, and this generates the bad signature.**

For information, here is the GPG error when trying to verify the key :

```
gpg: Signature made Sun Jul 25 23:55:39 2021 UTC
gpg:                using RSA key 4CE1877E19438C70
gpg: BAD signature from "TeX Live Distribution <tex-live@tug.org>" [unknown]
```

Here are the command I use (in a Dockerfile updated from [here](https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/images/texlive/-/blob/master/Dockerfile.latest)) :

```
ENV TLMIRRORURL=https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/

wget "$TLMIRRORURL/install-tl-unx.tar.gz" && \
wget "$TLMIRRORURL/install-tl-unx.tar.gz.sha512" && \
wget "$TLMIRRORURL/install-tl-unx.tar.gz.sha512.asc" && \
wget https://tug.org/texlive/files/texlive.asc && \
gpg --import texlive.asc && \
gpg --verify install-tl-unx.tar.gz.sha512.asc install-tl-unx.tar.gz.sha512 && \
sha512sum -c install-tl-unx.tar.gz.sha512 && \
```

This is the line that fails :

```
gpg --verify install-tl-unx.tar.gz.sha512.asc install-tl-unx.tar.gz.sha512 &&
```

Comment: Did you try to download from an explicit mirror instead of mirror.ctan? It just sends you to where it think is nearest you. If that nearest mirror is ad somehow...

Comment: They use an explicit mirror: https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/images/texlive/-/blob/master/Dockerfile.base#L17

Comment: Whether I'm using the CTAN multiplexer (that automagically chooses the nearest mirror), or an explicit, it doesn't changed anything.